# How to convert map and nested map to string and vise versa in Kotlin?

Tags: string, kotlin, dictionary, nested-map

I have no idea how to convert HashMap and nested Hashmap to string and vise versa:

I use Room to save data in a local database. The **"users "** hashmap is a parameter of the data class. To save this parameter **"users "** in the Room database, we must convert it to a primitive such as string, boolen, Integer, etc. Room does not support object references, so [type converters](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data) are required.

```
val users = HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Any>>()

    val user1 = HashMap<String, Any>()
    user1["filter"] = 0
    user1["group"] = "groupId"
    user1["labelsVisibility"] = true
    user1["sort"] = 1
    user1["view"] = 3
    users["user1"] = user1

    val user2 = HashMap<String, Any>()
    user2["filter"] = 0
    user2["group"] = "groupId"
    user2["labelsVisibility"] = true
    user2["sort"] = 1
    user2["view"] = 3
    users["user2"] = user2
```

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by "convert HashMap to String" and/or provide expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said earlier in the comments, it could be easily done with [Gson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.9.0) library:

```kotlin
// Configure Gson
val gson = GsonBuilder()
    // Using this strategy Gson first tries converting number to Long. 
    // If it fails (number is float), then it tries converting to Double
    .setObjectToNumberStrategy(ToNumberPolicy.LONG_OR_DOUBLE) 
    .create()

// Convert to JSON string
val jsonString = gson.toJson(users)
println("JSON => $jsonString")

// Store at Room as a string...
// Fetch later from Room as a string...

val type = object : TypeToken<HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Any>>>() {}.type
val fromJsonMap: HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Any>> = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type)

println("ORIGINAL MAP =>\n$users")
println("RESTORED MAP =>\n$fromJsonMap")
```

Output:

```
JSON => {
  "user1": {
    "filter": 0,
    "view": 3,
    "labelsVisibility": true,
    "sort": 1,
    "group": "groupId"
  },
  "user2": {
    "filter": 0,
    "view": 3,
    "labelsVisibility": true,
    "sort": 1,
    "group": "groupId"
  }
}

ORIGINAL MAP =>
{user1={filter=0, view=3, labelsVisibility=true, sort=1, group=groupId}, user2={filter=0, view=3, labelsVisibility=true, sort=1, group=groupId}}
RESTORED MAP =>
{user1={filter=0, view=3, labelsVisibility=true, sort=1, group=groupId}, user2={filter=0, view=3, labelsVisibility=true, sort=1, group=groupId}}
```

As you can see both original Map `users` and restored Map `fromJsonMap` are identical.

Comment: Yeah, this is really good solution, thank you.

Comment: But how to do it with `kotlinx.serialization`?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

There may be a better way to do this, but it works

1. converting a `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Any>>` to a string using special symbols * + (a symbols must be unique in string)

   ```
    fun fromUsersPreferences(users: HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Any>>): String {
      var usersString = ""
      users.forEach {
        usersString = usersString.plus("${it.key}*${it.value}+")
      }
      usersString = usersString.dropLast(1)
      return usersString
    }
   ```

**output:**

```
"user1*{filter=0, view=3, labelsVisibility=true, sort=1, group=groupId}+user2*{filter=1, view=1, labelsVisibility=false, sort=0, group=groupId}"
```

2. converting a string to a `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Any>>`

   ```
   fun toUsersPreferences(users: String): HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Any>> {
    val usersMap = users.split("+").associateTo(HashMap()){
        val list = it.split("*")
        val userKey = list[0]
        val userValue = list[1].removeSurrounding("{", "}").split(", ").associateTo(HashMap()){
            val (key, value) = it.split("=")
            if (key.equals("group")) {
                Pair<String, Any>(key, value)
            } else if (key.equals("labelsVisibility")) {
                Pair<String, Any>(key, value.toBoolean())
            } else {
                Pair<String, Any>(key, value.toInt())
            }
        }

        Pair(userKey, userValue)
    }

    return usersMap
   }
   ```

**output:**

```
{user1={filter=0, view=3, labelsVisibility=true, sort=1, group=groupId}, user2={filter=1, view=1, labelsVisibility=false, sort=0, group=groupId}}
```

Comment: Well, that looks bit overkill. Why don't you just use `Gson` library to convert Map to JSON (string) and back?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko I think you're right, but I don't know how to do it with Gson, post your solution if you can, thanks.

Comment: please see my Answer